# How to write Javascript code in an efficient way

Tags: javascript

I have a game where every time the user's score is 5, 10, or 15 it adds a new enemy. The numbers I randomly chose and intend to change later on.

I was able to figure out how to add new enemies every time the player reaches one of these scores but I have to make a new boolean variable for every new score. How can I write this same code in a smarter way without many booleans?

### Sketch.js

```
var addEnemyAt5= true; //boolean I have to create over and over
var addEnemyAt10 = true;
var addEnemyAt15 = true;
var score = 0;

if (score == 5 && enemyScore5) {
  console.log("new enemy at 5");
  addEnemyAt5 = false;

} else if (score == 10 && enemyScore10) {
  console.log("new enemy at 10");
  addEnemyAt10 = false;

} else if (score == 15 && enemyScore15) {
  console.log("new enemy at 15");
  addEnemyAt15 = false;
}
```

### HUD.js

```
this.scoreUpdate = function() {
  score += 5;
}
```

Comment: I answered your previous question. What do you think about my answer? http://stackoverflow.com/a/42896413/4831179

Comment: I don't understand. You say, every time it reaches any of the score. And in the if block you are here setting false.

Comment: @binariedMe my goal is to add a new enemy when a score reaches to a specific number. When I don't put false inside the if block it adds a new enemy over and over until the screen is full of enemies. I want to add only one enemy at a specific score.

Comment: @Sean The logic of your code is wonky. What if you change the your logic in your hud.js someday? score+=3 or something

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a `lastScore` variable to track when changes to `score` have been accounted for:

### Sketch.js:

```
var lastScore = 0
var score = 0

if (score > lastScore) {
  if (score === 5) {
    console.log("new enemy at 5")
  } else if (score === 10) {
    console.log("new enemy at 10")
  } else if (score === 15) {
    console.log("new enemy at 15")
  }
  lastScore = score
}
```

### HUD.js:

```
this.scoreUpdate = function() {
  score += 5
}
```

---

### Demo Snippet:

```js
var lastScore = 0
var score = 0

setInterval(function SketchDotJS() {

  if (score > lastScore) {
    if (score === 5) {
      console.log("new enemy at 5")
    } else if (score === 10) {
      console.log("new enemy at 10")
    } else if (score === 15) {
      console.log("new enemy at 15")
    }
    lastScore = score
  }

}, 10)

;(function HUDDotJS() {

  this.scoreUpdate = function() {
    score += 5
  }

})()
```

```html
<!-- Boilerplate code to get the demo to work -->
<button onclick="scoreUpdate()">Increase <var>score</var> by 5</button>
<pre><var>score</var> = <span id="score">0</span></pre>
<script>setInterval(function(e){score===+e.textContent||(e.textContent=score)},10,document.getElementById('score'))</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try perhaps:

```
createEnemyAtScore = {
    5: true,
    10: true,
    15: true
};
var score = 10;

if (createEnemyAtScore[score]) {
    // create your enemy... or whatever..
}
```

but I would suggest moving this question to [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 1):

You can organize theme into an object

```
var milestoneMet = {
    5: false,
    10: false,
    15: false
};

// for each milestone, check and set milestoneMet
```